# float enumeration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, enums, floating-point

In my algorithm i need check for zero.

For this matter i need EPSILON.

How can i define it best?

```
classdef QR
    enumeration 
        EPSILON (1e-6)
    end

    methods (Static)
        function [Q, R] = Classical(A)
            ...
                if R(c, c) < EPSILON
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

But, i get:

> In definition of enumeration member 'EPSILON' in class 'QR': Too many
>   input arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of your enumeration class is getting called with the value you pass to EPSILON. Also, while not required with your example code, I would probably separate the enumeration definition from the other classes, since the only instances of the enumeration classes that can be created are in fact created in the enumeration block. More info on how enumerations work [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html). Also, rather than static methods for the different QR algorithms you might want to consider utilizing a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This would look something like:

NamedValues.m

```
classdef NamedValues < double
    enumeration 
        EPSILON (1e-6)
    end
end
```

ClassicalStrategy.m

```
classdef ClassicalQRStrategy
    methods
        function [Q, R] = compute(strategy, A)
            ...
                if R(c, c) < NamedValues.EPSILON
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

QR.m

```
classdef QRAlgorithm
    properties
        Strategy
    end
    methods
        function algorithm = QRAlgorithm(strategy)
            algorithm.Strategy = strategy;
        end
        function [Q, R] = compute(algorithm, A)
            [Q, R] = algorithm.Strategy.compute(A);
        end
    end
end
```